# Whats the technical difference between sending a webpage request and sending an email?

Tags: email, http, imap, pop3, network-protocols

I need some clarity on this topic.

Here is what I understand: a webpage request initiates a DNS lookup and once domain name is resolved into an IP address, browser sends a request to that IP address for the webpage in question. The web server, listening to some specific port, receives the request and serves it.

Sending an email, initiates a DNS lookup and once the IP address of the email server is located, an email request [with its content] is sent to that IP address. The email server, listening to some specific port, receives the request and post the email in the account mentioned in the request.

Comment: They use different ports and require the client to speak different protocols. See the RFCs of SMTP and HTTP for more information.

Comment: Beyond the fact one is over http and the other uses an entirely different protocol?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/262570/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpages use HTTP, email uses SMTP for sending and POP3/IMAP/Exchange for remote retrieval/manipulation of a store of messages.

All these are different.

HTTP is a request-response protocol, meaning the client issues a single request, and the server provides a response, and that's it.  It is by design *stateless*, meaning there is no notion of a session - the server doesn't remember successive requests from a client.  However, through the use of *cookies* it's possible to build sessions "on top of" HTTP.  HTTP commands (a.k.a. *methods*) are designed to work with URLs.  URLs can be a static document living on the web server or output of a program that creates a response on the fly which the web server forwards.

SMTP is a session-oriented protocol, you open an SMTP session and can issue more than one request or command per session.  For example, specifying a recipient can be a single command, as is providing authentication details.  Specifying the message is a separate command in itself, and you or your email client can issue more commands afterward in the same session.  The SMTP commands are designed to work with email addresses, and are for sending messages to an email server only.

POP3 and IMAP are similar to SMTP in how they look and function, but have commands dedicated to retrieving or manipulating messages on a server instead of sending messages.  A POP3 client would issue a command to list messages, issue further commands to obtain them, and then follow up with delete commands, all in the same connection or session.  IMAP works similar but with more advanced commands that allow manipulation of folders.  Not sure how Exchange works in detail but it's likely similar in concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, email, smtp is port 25 or 465,587 with encryption.
Web port 80, or 443 encrypted.

However, each one has its own language.  For example a web server mainly uses the GET,POST, and PUT commands for 99% of traffic and has approx 12 total commands.

An email server also has a very limited vocabulary of email specific commands.

See http://the-welters.com/professional/smtp.html and google the RFC for each for detailed info.

Also web servers are interested in sharing their content with the world and email/smtp servers don't share there content with the world.

Anyone can send you and email, but the server requires your login/password to see it.  Some websites have logins, but most have some amount of public information.